# Install stage-packages .deb from local path ubuntu:focal

Tags: snap, python3

Below is a sample of the snapcraft.YAML file I use to build my app.

```
parts:
  TEST:
    plugin: python
    source: .
    requirements:
      - snap/local/requirements.txt
    build-packages:
      - build-essential
      - git
      - libxslt1-dev
      - python3-setuptools
    stage-packages:
      - avahi-utils
      - bind9
      - chrony
      - python3-django
      - python3-django-piston3
```

I want to use a particular version for `python3-django-piston3` which is part of stage-packages.

I have stored the file `python3-django-piston3_0.5.1-306-g.4d801e8~ubuntu20.04.1_all.deb` on local path. I want snapcraft to take `stage-package python3-django-piston3` from my local path and build app.

Could you please provide the steps?